# addListSelectionListener invoke every time there is change in selection

Tags: java, jtable

I have Jtable with some rows. If I make selection to some rows, the `addListSelectionListener` gets invoked each time(for each row selection). Is there any way I can avoid these multiple invoking, as it slows down the process if I select 10000s of rows

Code which shows the selection of the rows

```
for (int i = 0; i < sArray.length; i++)
        {
            // int viewindex = mTableForActionListener.getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToView(i);
            mTableForActionListener.addRowSelectionInterval(sArray[i].intValue(), sArray[i].intValue());
        }
```

`mDocListTable` is instance of `mTableForActionListener`. Code where it gets invoked

```
mDocListTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
        {
            handle_TableSelection(e);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Remove the listener before your for loop and add it back after for loop.

```
ListSelectionListener listener = new ListSelectionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
    {
        handle_TableSelection(e);
    }
};

mDocListTable.getSelectionModel().removeListSelectionListener(listener);    
for (int i = 0; i < sArray.length; i++)
{
    mTableForActionListener.addRowSelectionInterval(sArray[i].intValue(), sArray[i].intValue());
}
mDocListTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(listener);
// add some code here to deal with the new selections in the table.
```

**Solution 2:**

In the `ListSelectionEvent`, check if there's still adjusting taking place.

```
mDocListTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getValueIsAdjusting()） return;
        handle_TableSelection(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that. But I cant do that as its implemented in different classes( and I am not so good in java). Do you think getValueIsAdjusting can help me? Like passing some value to addListSelectionListener, to invoke only once when I ask?

Comment: Yes, if you still wanna handle these events, you can use `getValuesIsAdjusting()` method in your `ListSelectionListener`'s method. If this returns true, which means there is still adjusting going on, just return and if it's false, then call you `handle_TableSelection()` method.

Comment: I think I will go with your idea of remove and adding listener before the for loop. Only question is what would Ii add as "listener" (in argument). Can you give please me example?

Comment: @user1631306 just define your listener as a variable. See my update

Comment: @user1631306 If you only care about what the selected rows are in the end, then do the removing and adding back listener solution, this will make no call to the listener at all. And after your for loop, just call a method to check what rows are selected in the table and do your operations on them.

Comment: can we talk on chat for 5 min.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109180/discussion-between-user1631306-and-keqiang-li).